# Retrieving mutiple row data from sql by php executed under joomla

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I have a sql query working fine. However after execution (php form in joomla inserted with sourcerer plugin) resulting array stays empty.

sql code:

```
SELECT `comid`,`comname`,`comlogo`    
FROM ffd_companies,ffd_comusercon,ffd_users    
WHERE companyid=comid AND userid=id AND id=1;
```

code in joomla->customHTMLmodule->sourcerer:

```
{source}
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo $user->id;

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('comid','comname')));
$query->from($db->quoteName(array('ffd_companies','ffd_comusercon','ffd_users')));
$query->where($db->quoteName('companyid').' = '.$db->quoteName('comid').' AND '.$db->quote('userid') .' = '. $db->quote('id').' AND '. $db->quote('userid') .' = '.$db->quote($user->id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRowList();
print_r($row);
?>
{/source}
```

Tables & Relations :

SQL query: SELECT * FROM `ffd_users`;
id ...
standar joomla users table nothing changed

SQL query: SELECT * FROM `ffd_comusercon`; (Index table for Many to many rel. between. users and companies)
companyid (FOREIGN KEY OF comid ) userid (FOREIGN KEY OF id )

SQL query: SELECT * FROM `ffd_companies`;
comid comname comtype comlogo comyedek1 comyedek2 omyedek3 comyedek4 comyedek5 comyedek6 comyedek7 comyedek8

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();
echo $user->id;

$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('comid','comname')))
  ->from($db->quoteName(array('ffd_companies','ffd_comusercon','ffd_users')))
  ->where($db->quoteName('companyid').' = '.$db->quoteName('comid'))
  ->where($db->quote('userid') .' = '. $db->quote('id'))
  ->where($db->quote('userid') .' = '.$db->quote($user->id));
$db->setQuery($query);

$row = $db->loadObjectList();
var_dump($row);
?>
```

Update query (with left joins), *it's only a guess without database structure, but i guess you get the point*

```
$query->select('COMP.id AS comid, COMP.name as comname')->
  from($db->quoteName('#__companies') . ' COMP')->
  join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__comusercon') . ' COMPX ON COMP.id = COMPX.company_id')->
  join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__users') . ' USR ON USR.id = COMPX.user_id')->
  where('USR.id = ' . $db->quote($user->id))->
  group('COMP.id');
```

Comment: Good answer di3sel. @user2102266, just on a side note, you should use `#__` rather than `ffd_` to define the database tables. This is a generic prefix so that if you ever decide to change the table prefixes, then your scripts won't be affacted ;)

Comment: nope i get exactly same result. However it really helped me to see what i miss.

Comment: I believe than you need to join additional tables ffd_comusercon AND ffd_users. Is there any relations between tables (id's or something), or maybe you can update your question with database tables structure, so i could write joins correctly.

Comment: I put the relation and table infos. I m not confortable with using JOIN NULL  values will be everywhere. I think its about AND operators.

Answer (score 0):

After countless of rewrite finally it gave same result with the pure sql.

```
<?php
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('comid', 'comname','comlogo') ) );
$query->from($db->quoteName(array('ffd_companies',ffd_comusercon,'ffd_users') ) );
$query->where($db->quoteName('companyid') .' = '. $db->quoteName('comid') .' AND '. $db->quoteName('userid') .' = '. $db->quoteName('id') .' AND '. $db->quoteName('userid')  .' = '. $db->quote($user->id)
);
$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRowList();
print_r($row);
?>
```